# Auto Scroll of Controls in Div

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

Kindly help me to sort out this below issue.

Currently I have a Div and I have Panel inside Div.

```
 <div id="Ord1"> <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrd1" runat="server"> Dynamic HTML Tables.... </asp:Panel> </div>
```

Now I have created dynamice table controls and added to the Panel which is placed inside the Div( Div>Panel>Dynamic Tables).

If the number of dynamic tables is more than 5 then I need to auto scroll the talbes one by one from left to right with equal intervals.

Note: My Page will have 4 Divs and each dive will have Panel inside the Div. Suppose in Second Div if the dynamic tables is less than 5 there is no need of auto scroll to be done.

Thanks,

David.

Comment: Do you want a scrollbar, or do you want something like a switch which moves all tables at once?

Answer (score 0):

pls refere the below code...

```
<div style="overflow:auto; width:1000px; height:400px;" id="Ord1"> <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrd1" runat="server"> Dynamic HTML Tables.... </asp:Panel> </div>
```